# CorelDraw VBA Hatchfill color

Tags: vba, colors, fill, coreldraw

Anyone have an idea how to get the background and line color from a custom hatch fill?

the following code fills the selected shape using data from textboxes

```
      ActiveSelectionRange.ApplyCustomHatchFill ANG.value, LS.value, 0, 0, 0, LT.value, CreateRGBColor(255, 0, 0), BackColor:=CreateRGBColor(255, 255, 255)
```

this works fine I also have a color picker that changes the color of the line and background which is fine but if you change the line size the color changes back to what is specified in the code above

what I need  to get is the current color of the line and backcolor in the selected shape so that I can change the line thickess while retaining the set color

i have a feeling its something to do with GET patternfill.backcolor but I cant find any examples on its usage

Any help is appreciated

mark

UPDATE

OK I have found the following gets the back colour into  a string

value = s.Fill.Hatch.BackColor.ToString

I can then do a split and  get the values

But there doesn't seem to be an option for getting the line colour (Forecolor)

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

## Hatch Fill

A shape's hatch fill is a [HatchFill](https://community.coreldraw.com/sdk/api/draw/20/c/hatchfill) object. It has one `BackColor` and one or multiple `Patterns()`.
Each pattern has an `Outline` (specifying the line in the pattern) which has a `Color` which can be read by e. g. `ToString` or other [methods](https://community.coreldraw.com/sdk/api/draw/20/c/color) to read a color.

If you want to change other properties of your hatch fill lines, please see all the properties and methods of an `Outline` [here](https://community.coreldraw.com/sdk/api/draw/20/c/outline)

Some examples:

```
s.Fill.Hatch.BackColor                  ' background color
s.Fill.Hatch.Patterns(1).Outline.Color  ' line color of first pattern
s.Fill.Hatch.Patterns(1).Outline.Width  ' line width of first pattern
```

You may also check, if it really has an opaque background: [`Fill.Hatch.HasBackground`](https://community.coreldraw.com/sdk/api/draw/20/p/hatchfill.hasbackground)

## Pattern Fill

Just in case: A pattern fill is simpler and has only two colors:

```
s.Fill.Pattern.FrontColor
s.Fill.Pattern.BackColor
```

Comment: Hi Asger Hatch.patterns works but gives me the background colour Patterns.front colour throws an error saying wrong fill type I need the front colour of the hatchfill cant believe this is soooo hard

Comment: How many `Fill.Hatch.Patterns.Count` does your shape have? Please check which `Outline.Color` all these items have. Please check `Patterns(0)` also.

Comment: Hi Asgar The Count is 1 If I check patterns(0) it throws an error saying has to be between 1 and 1

Comment: You "have a color picker that changes the color of the line", but how or what does that change? There might be the problem. If you don't change the `Hatch.Patterns(1).Outline.Color` by that color picker, it remains as predefined.

Comment: You also change the "line size". If you meant the line width, I also added an example.